# Change color of send message bar (JSQMessagesViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am adding chat functionality to my app using JSQMessagesViewController. I am going with a dark theme and made the chat dark except for the send message bar. I have not been able to figure out how to change its color (See screenshot below). Can someone tell me how to change the color of the send message bar?

Thanks!

[image: ChatExample]

Comment: this is the content view that you need to reference and customize... http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.2.0/Classes/JSQMessagesInputToolbar.html#//api/name/contentView

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed. I added the code below to viewDidLoad() and it worked. self.inputToolbar.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I changed it. Thanks Sargeras for the help.

`self.inputToolbar.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()`